# How to Broadcast elements to only certain ranks without using the MPI_Send and MPI_Recv routines

Tags: c, performance, mpi, broadcast, collect

Just a general question:

I wanted to ask if there is anyway to broadcast elements to only certain ranks in MPI without using the `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` routines.

Comment: That is not how MPI is meant to work. That being said, you can create an ad-hoc communicator with only these ranks and then `MPI_Bcast()`. Or you can use `MPI_Scatterv()` (the other elements still have to invoke `MPI_Scatterv(..., recvcount=0, ...)` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to ask if there is anyway to broadcast elements to only
> certain ranks in MPI without using the MPI_Send MPI_Recv.

Let us start by looking at the description of the **[MPI_Bcast](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Bcast.html)** routine.

> Broadcasts a message from the process with rank "root" to all other
> **processes of the communicator**

The `MPI_Bcast` broadcast routine is a collective communication. [Hence](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-broadcast-and-collective-communication/):

> Collective communication is a method of communication which involves
> participation **of all processes in a communicator.**

Notice the text in bold *i.e.,* *"all processes in a communicator"*. Therefore, one approach (to achieve what you want) is to create a subset composed of the processes that will participate in the broadcast routine. This subset can be materialized through the creation of a new MPI [communicator](http://www.rc.usf.edu/tutorials/classes/tutorial/mpi/chapter9.html). To create that communicator one can use the MPI function [MPI_Comm_split](http://MPI_Comm_split). About that routine from [source](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/introduction-to-groups-and-communicators/) one can read:

> **As the name implies, `MPI_Comm_split` creates new communicators by
> “splitting” a communicator into a group of sub-communicators based on
> the input values color and key.** It’s important to note here that the
> original communicator doesn’t go away, but a new communicator is
> created on each process. 
> The first argument, comm, is the communicator
> that will be used as the basis for the new communicators. This could
> be MPI_COMM_WORLD, but it could be any other communicator as well. 
> T**he second argument, color, determines to which new communicator each
> processes will belong. All processes which pass in the same value for
> color are assigned to the same communicator. If the color is
> MPI_UNDEFINED, that process won’t be included in any of the new
> communicators.** The third argument, key, determines the ordering (rank)
> within each new communicator. The process which passes in the smallest
> value for key will be rank 0, the next smallest will be rank 1, and so
> on. If there is a tie, the process that had the lower rank in the
> original communicator will be first. The final argument, newcomm is
> how MPI returns the new communicator back to the user.

Let us say that we wanted to have only the processes with an even rank to participate in the `MPI_Bcast`; We would first create the communicator:

```
MPI_Comm new_comm;
int color = (world_rank % 2  == 0) ? 1 : MPI_UNDEFINED;
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, world_rank, &new_comm);
```

and eventually call the `MPI_Bcast` for the new communicator:

```
    if(world_rank % 2  == 0){
        ....
        MPI_Bcast(&bcast_value, 1, MPI_INT, 0, new_comm);
        ...
   }
```

At the end we would free the memory used by the communicator:

```
    MPI_Comm_free(&new_comm);
```

A running code example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); // Initialize the MPI environment
    int world_rank; 
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);
    int bcast_value = world_rank;  
    MPI_Bcast(&bcast_value, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = %d, bcast_value = %d \n", world_rank, bcast_value);

    MPI_Comm new_comm;
    int color = (world_rank % 2  == 0) ? 1 : MPI_UNDEFINED;
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, world_rank, &new_comm); 
   
    if(world_rank % 2  == 0){
    int new_comm_rank, new_comm_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(new_comm, &new_comm_rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(new_comm, &new_comm_size);
        bcast_value = 1000;
        MPI_Bcast(&bcast_value, 1, MPI_INT, 0, new_comm);
    
    printf("MPI_Bcast 2 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = %d, new_comm = %d, bcast_value = %d \n", world_rank, new_comm_rank,  bcast_value);
        MPI_Comm_free(&new_comm);
   }
   MPI_Finalize(); 
   return 0;
 }
```

This code example, showcases two `MPI_Bcast` calls, one with all the processes of the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` (*i.e.,* `MPI_Bcast 1`)  and another with only a subset of those processes (*i.e.,* `MPI_Bcast 2`).

The output (for 8 processes):

```
MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 0, bcast_value = 0 
MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 4, bcast_value = 0 
MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 5, bcast_value = 0 
MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 6, bcast_value = 0 
MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 7, bcast_value = 0 
MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 1, bcast_value = 0 
MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 2, bcast_value = 0 
MPI_Bcast 1 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 3, bcast_value = 0 
MPI_Bcast 2 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 0, new_comm = 0, bcast_value = 1000 
MPI_Bcast 2 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 4, new_comm = 2, bcast_value = 1000 
MPI_Bcast 2 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 2, new_comm = 1, bcast_value = 1000 
MPI_Bcast 2 : MPI_COMM_WORLD ProcessID = 6, new_comm = 3, bcast_value = 1000
```